# Is lenovo v110 god for programming?

Tags: laptop

[https://www.newegg.com/p/1TS-000E-0CTV4?Description=lenovo%20v110&cm_re=lenovo_v110-*-9SIAA0S8R50297-*-Product](https://www.newegg.com/p/1TS-000E-0CTV4?Description=lenovo%20v110&cm_re=lenovo_v110-_-9SIAA0S8R50297-_-Product)

(I know this is not top notch)
I need a captain who tell me if this is good for programming (c#, .net)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I don't think it will suffice.

Firstly it has 4gb of RAM, which will be maxed out relatively quick.

Then the dual core processor will not be able to handle any programs unless it's a small, simple one.

It will be able to write code, but it will definitely not be a pleasant experience.